# Issue with AMCharts Series not appearing when The data has less than 3 values

Tags: javascript, jquery, amcharts

I am using AMCharts4 in a WordPress Project, everything works fine, but I am having a weird issue when I filter the data, let me show what's happening with images:

- With All the data (Works 100% fine)
  [image: Image Working Fine]

-Filtering the data (More than 2 results works fine 100%)

[image: Filtering Data working]

- Filtering the data (2 or Less results not showing the Scores, here is the bug)

[image]

See how it's not showing the respective scores as the 2 first images.

The question here is how do I make those scores appear? I have tried commented lines of code in my funcions but nothing seems to work.

You could reproduce the issue in this [link](https://ktccidtdsdev.wpengine.com/benchmark/) selecting the Australia or Brazil location for example

And see my function [here](https://jsfiddle.net/naexLqw6/)

```
labelBullet = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.LabelBullet())
labelBullet.label.horizontalCenter = "left";
labelBullet.label.dx = 10;
labelBullet.label.text = "{values.valueX.workingValue.formatNumber('#.')}";
labelBullet.locationX = 1;
```

Comment: Hi @ricardo, have you found anything yet. I am also having the same specific issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is in your usage of `labelBullet.locationX = 1;`. If you take a look at [am4 Bullets documentation](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/bullets/#Positioning_within_column):

> There's one caveat, though. For bullets, locationY property means the
> relative vertical position in the whole height of the column. That
> means that if our scale would not start at zero, it would be not in
> the direct center of the currently visible portion of the column.

As you are using inverted chart, same applies to `locationX` in your case. Meaning, label position is relative to the scale.

To fix the issue you can either set `min` for value axis to 0, as in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h6gksvxc/3/) using:

```
valueAxis.min = 0;
```

or as mentioned in the document, push labels directly into column series template, as in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h6gksvxc/4/).

```
label = series.columns.template.createChild(am4core.Label);
label.text = "{values.valueX.workingValue.formatNumber('#.')}";
label.align = "left";
label.valign = "middle";
label.zIndex = 2;
```